# Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected flutter

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart

I am using agora official pub flutter package, but following error throwing when i try to run project

/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-5.1.0/android/src/main/kotlin/io/agora/agora_rtc_engine/AgoraRtcEnginePlugin.kt: (251, 18): Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected

Comment: You are getting null value instead of string. Consider including your code snippet

Comment: this error coming from package code, not from my own code

Comment: If you are certain about this, creating git issue might help

Comment: I think, it related to package compatibility for flutter 3.0, because on 2.0 it's working fine

Comment: What is your flutter version and dart version?

Comment: When I updated agora package from 1.0.3 to 1.0.5 latest, it's working

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution

I just updated agora pub package version to latest. Now it's working